# Maven shared module in Spring Boot with test utilities

Tags: spring-boot, maven, module

I have a doubt about which solution is better to share utilities between maven modules.

The problem is that we have 2 maven modules for 2 api type modules and another "shared" module with logic used by those two modules.
In this "shared" module there are also utility classes for tests, for example, an abstract class "MockMvcTest.java" that are used in the other modules to not repeat code. All classes are shared directly, are not declared within test packages, and are not shared as tests. That is, in this "shared" module test dependencies, such as "junit-vintage-engine", cannot have "test" scope.

This "shared" module ends up containing packages with test utilities, security, mappers, etc.
I have doubts about whether it is okay to mix "normal" and "test" logic in this "shared" module and share it with the other modules or would be better to create another module?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: you should write unit tests for the given module, dont share them in other modules, you can mock the shared module code in your other module so it wont be an dependency for testing

Comment: hello, it is not that we need to mock the "shared" classes, some are specific utility classes for tests, for example an abstract class "MockMvcTest.java" that are used in the other modules so as not to repeat code

Comment: i dont agree on sharing test code with the business code. may be you can move them to shared tests folder and import it on other two modules tests

Comment: this is opinion based, voted to close